# Is there an online assembly instruction manual

Tags: assembly, x86

There is a pdf version of assembly language instructions reference from [intel](http://developer.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/243191.htm), but as you know, an online version would be more convenient as my browser is always open, within one click I get the information I want.

Does anyone know if there is an online version of assembly instruction manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this one.](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/intel.html)

Comment: This one is useful, but seems not latest and complete

Answer (score 2):

http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: Thanks, but seems this one doesn't quite serve as an instruction manual.